# Using both Backbone.js and Angular.js in same project. What is the feasibility and practical implications ?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

I've been doing some work with Angular.js for quite some time now. Recently in my project, there was a requirement of a SPA application and I am assigned a module to design.
The developer who already did some work on this project, chosen Backbone.js as the basis for implementing MVC.

Now, since i am pretty much conversant with Angular, learning Backbone from the scratch is getting a bit difficult and time consuming.

Is there a possibility, of using Backbone and Angular hand in hand in same application ? The Models and Views for my module are independent of the work done by my teammate. But both the modules would go together in the final application.

Can you let me know the feasibility of this ? And if possible, what would be the practical implementations and overheads if any. I intend not to touch the code written in Backbone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone and Angular can certainly be used together (although I wouldn't exactly recommend it).  You probably want to stick to only using the Collections/Models/Routers from Backbone, as trying to combine Backbone.View with Angular will likely result in confusing code.  However, you could use both if you really wanted, as long as you made sure that the Angular contexts don't overlap with your Backbone Views (and even then, you *could* overlap the two, but all bets are off if you try to do that).

Answer (score 0):

Better use Restangular, it extends Angular with similarly things you probably like in Backbone.